# Trouble with Pagination - Not displaying

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3 and the Roots Theme.

i have a page called 'portfolio' that displays 6 portfolio items out of a total of 15,

I am using the following code:

/proman/assets/img/code011.jpg" alt="Folio Feature Image">

```
    <!-- Add the pagination functions here. -->
<?php   $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $query_recents = new WP_Query ( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => $paged ) );
        if ( $query_recents->have_posts() ): 
            ?>

<!-- Start of the main loop. -->
 <?php while ( $query_recents->have_posts() ) : $query_recents->the_post(); ?>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
    <!-- the rest of your theme's main loop -->
       <?php get_template_part('templates/folio', get_post_format()); ?>
   </div>


<?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- End of the main loop -->

<!-- Add the pagination functions here. -->

<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>

<?php else : ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but nothing displays at all. I have looked at the codex as I was told this doesnt work for single page templates , Ive tried all kinds of varieties but nothing will display.

This has worked for me previously in a none bootstrap environment, Im not sure what I need to do.

would appreciate if anyone has an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have your variable `$paged` defined?

If not, add above your code

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

Comment: I have added that now, thank you. but it still doesn't output anything. I have included my whole page template in the code now. 
instead of links there are just empty divs

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using roots and bootstrap 3 with a portfolio while integrating the  .thumbnail component.

check here: http://calebserna.com/portfolio/

It's working great. My solution was to create a category 'portfolio' then edit 'templates/content.php'.

```
<?php if(is_category('192')) : ?>
<div 
<?php post_class('col-xs-6 col-md-3'); ?>  >    
  <!-- bootstrap 3 thumbnails component -->
  <div class="thumbnail">
  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
  <?php the_post_thumbnail('bootstrap_portfolio_thumb'); ?>
  </a>
  <?php } ?>
  <div class="caption">
<?php the_title(); ?>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php else : ?>
<?php
//the default content loop below
```

then edit config.php so a sidebar does not appear in  category 'portfolio'.

if you really want to use a custom page with wp_query try inserting the defaul roots paging code in your template

```
 //index.php 
<?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
  <nav class="post-nav">
    <ul class="pager">
      <li class="previous"><?php next_posts_link(__('&larr; Older posts', 'roots')); ?></li>
      <li class="next"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer posts &rarr;', 'roots')); ?></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```